# How to 2 row to calculation find special 2 words?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below:

```
Date                              Msg

2019-04-11 10:14:02.773           AB123  <this is Succec bec next line is CD   
2019-04-11 10:14:02.647           CD123      
2019-04-11 10:11:03.670           AB123      
2019-04-11 10:11:03.500           CD123     
2019-04-10 09:53:39.743           AB123 <this is fail bec next line is not CD
2019-04-10 09:52:39.743           AB123
2019-04-10 09:53:39.743           CD123
2019-04-10 09:52:39.743           AB123 <this is fail bec next line is not CD
2019-04-10 09:52:39.743           AB123 <this is fail bec next line is NULL
```

I want to find Msg top 2 row AB and CD is success ORDER BY Date

If Msg have AB continue to appearance will fail until CD 1 set

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `Id` INTEGER,
  `Date` DATETIME,
  `Msg` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`Id`, `Date`, `Msg`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2019-04-11 10:14:02.773', 'AB123'),
  ('2', '2019-04-11 10:14:02.647', 'CD123'),
  ('3', '2019-04-11 10:11:03.670', 'AB123'),
  ('4', '2019-04-11 10:11:03.500', 'CD123'),
  ('5', '2019-04-10 09:53:39.743', 'AB123'),
  ('6', '2019-04-09 09:53:39.587', 'AB123'),
  ('7', '2019-04-09 09:53:39.001', 'CD123'),
  ('8', '2019-04-08 07:53:39.587', 'AB123'), 
  ('9', '2019-04-07 08:53:39.111', 'AB123');

SELECT t.Id, t.Date, t.Msg 
FROM ( SELECT Id, Date, Msg, LEAD(Msg) OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS NextMsg FROM table1 ) t 
WHERE t.Msg LIKE '%AB%' AND t.NextMsg LIKE '%AB%'  
ORDER BY t.Date DESC
```

My expected output is

```
Id  Date                Msg    Check
5   2019-04-10 09:53:40 AB123  fail
8   2019-04-08 07:53:40 AB123  fail
9  2019-04-07 08:53:39  AB123  fail
```

Example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9B2LzaAvwhFz1QRN53moQU/4

Comment: I removed the tags for Postgres and SQLite as the non-standard SQL you are using is clearly for SQL Server

Comment: `SELECT TOP 2 Id,Date,Msg` ... that's all, as I understand

Comment: I m sorry there only have AB AND CD type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to filter your table using the values in current and subsequent rows, next approach using [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) may help:

Input

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Id int,
    [Date] datetime,
    Msg varchar(5)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
    (Id, [Date], Msg)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-04-11T10:14:02.773', 'AB123'),      
    (2, '2019-04-11T10:14:02.647', 'CD123'),      
    (3, '2019-04-11T10:11:03.670', 'AB123'),      
    (4, '2019-04-11T10:11:03.500', 'CD123'),     
    (5, '2019-04-10T09:53:39.743', 'AB123'),
    (6, '2019-04-10T09:52:39.743', 'AB123')
```

Statement

```
SELECT t.Id, t.[Date], t.[Msg]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Id, 
        [Date], 
        Msg, 
        LEAD(Msg) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS NextMsg
    FROM #Data  
) t
WHERE t.Msg LIKE '%AB%' AND ((t.NextMsg NOT LIKE '%CD%') OR (t.NextMsg IS NULL))
ORDER BY t.[Date] DESC
```

Output

```
Id  Date                Msg
5   10/04/2019 09:53:39 AB123
6   10/04/2019 09:52:39 AB123
```

Comment: thanks bro i want to ask if next line is Null or nothing if fail how can to do?

Comment: @KwanNick Just use appropriate `WHERE` clause. `NextMsg` holds the value for subsequent row. See updated answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I guess what you want is this ,this will work:

```
select a.*,case when regexp_like(a.Msg,'(.)*AB(.)*')=1 or
regexp_like(a.Msg,'(.)*CD(.)*')=1 then 'IsSuccess' 
when regexp_like(a.Msg,'(.)*EF(.)*')=1 then 'IsFail'
else null end  status from table1 a
```

check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9B2LzaAvwhFz1QRN53moQU/0

Comment: sorry my Expression is wrong thank u so much bro I want to ORDER BY Date and show one fail

Comment: SQL Server does not support `regexp_like()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to find "AB" values that don't have a "CD" value within some timeframe -- say 1 second or 1 minute.

If so, use `not exists`:

select t.*
from t
where t.msg like 'AB%' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.msg like 'CD%' and
                        t2.date < t.date and
                        t2.date >= dateadd(second, -10, t.date)
                 );